# Symmetry Factor and Wicks Theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams, wick-theorem

I have a problem with a particular kind of exercise. The question is:

> *Consider* $\phi^4$-*theory with* $\mathcal{L}_\text{int}=-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$. *Give the symmetry factors of the diagram and prove it using Wick contractions.*
>
> [image]

My attempt for the symmetry factor is:

A factor $2$ for the left loop, cause it can be mirrored without changing something and a factor $3!$ for the right bubble, cause the 3 inner propagators can be interchanged with each other. So the symmetry factor is $2\cdot 3! = 12$.

Now I'm really unsure how to prove (or find a mistake) with Wick contractions. My first thought was to right down the correlator to the third order of perturbation theory:

$\left<p_1|\phi(z_1)\phi(z_1)\phi(z_1)\phi(z_1)\phi(z_2)\phi(z_2)\phi(z_2)\phi(z_2)\phi(z_3)\phi(z_3)\phi(z_3)\phi(z_3)|p_2\right>$

where $p_i$ are the external momentum and $z_i$ are the internal vertices.

Then my guess was to find all possible way to fully contract the fields with each other in such a way that it would lead to the diagram and show that this also give 12 ways of doing this.

But how can I know if I found all of them and how is this a prove then?

Furthermore I find it really confusing and tedious on a paper, is there a good way to make this efficient? Especially for larger diagrams this method seems impossible.

I found different threads for Wick and symmetry factors, but non off them really covers my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may help is to write down the point coordinates in your diagram, that correspond to the coordinates in the correlator. Lets say $z_1$ is the vertex point for the simple loop on the left and $z_2, z_3$ are the vertex points of the "right bubble" from left to right.

Now you see, that you need a connection between $z_1$ and $z_2$ (the middle horizontal line in your diagram). In your correlator, this corresponds to contraction terms with any of the fields $\phi(z_1)$ with any of $\phi(z_2)$ contracted together. You can see that this leads to $4\cdot 4=16$ possibilities. Then you need to close the loop in $z_1$, which you can do by choosing one of the three remaining $\phi(z_1)$ and contract it with any of the two $\phi(z_1)$ left. This gives $3$ additional combinations. The one field in $z_1$ left is later contracted with your external field. You do the same considerations on the right: Take the three fields left at $z_2$ and connect them with any three fields at $z_3$, which are $4\cdot 3\cdot 2=24$ combinations. Then there is a factor 3!, since we choose a unique assignment of the points $z_1, z_2, z_3$ but need to consider all possible assignments.

In total, you therefore have $16\cdot 3\cdot 24\cdot 3!=6912$ possible combinations. However, the correlator alone will not give you the symmetry factor. For that you also need to consider the perturbative expansion (which will give a factor $\frac{1}{3!}$ in the Taylor series) and the $\frac{1}{4!}$ factor from the interaction term in the Lagrangian (we have this 3 times, since 3 vertices are being used). This leads to a total factor of
$$\frac{6912}{3!\cdot (4!)^3}=\frac{1}{12} \ ,$$
which is exactly the symmetry factor, by which you have to multiply in the total amplitude for this diagram.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot. To just find the symmetry factor, does the method I used above work or was it luck that it matched? And for "prove it using Wick contractions" I can use this method then?

Comment: @Luc4aa Yes, the symmetry factor is usually retrieved by the method you mentioned. This works, since the factor from the Taylor expansion always cancels against the amount of vertex assignments and the factor from the interaction vertex cancels against the amount of ways to contract fields into this vertex. What remains is then exactly just the amount of ways to interchange the internal propagators such that the diagram is unchanged. Since this is the only method I know to derive the symmetry factor, I suppose it suffices as a prove after comparing it with your method.